# Glass sound missing in Apple Mail on macOS Monterey

Tags: mail.app, audio, email

I'm using Apple Mail 16.0 (3696.120.41.1.1) on macOS Monterey 12.6.2 (21G320).

I remember there used to be a sound called “Glass” or similar. I was using this for incoming e-mails some months/years ago.

You can hear that sound [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xfq35-PCfkk).

Unfortunately, I cannot find that sound in the list of sounds in Mail preferences any more:

[image: Mail list of sounds]

Is there a way to use this sound for incoming e-mails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `/System/Library/Sounds/Glass.aiff` from an older system (before Big Sur) and place it into...

```
~/Library/Sounds/
```

Since the new glass sound still exists, but has been renamed to "Crystal" in System Preferences, or System Settings, renaming it to something else (e.g. in my case Glass-orig) might be advised.
It should then appear in Mail as an option to select as "new messages sound".

The above should also answer your second question as to why Apple removed it: they did not really remove it, but modernised it with the new "Glass.aiff" sound (as it's called in Finder), which displays as Crystal in the System Preferences.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The old solution, copying Glass.aiff from /System/Library/Sounds off a Mac running macOS Monterey or earlier, does not work anymore.

You may wish to [file feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html) about this regression; Apple has (unfortunately) been making many recent decisions changing macOS to only have the same options as i*OS.  (Since i*OS can't have custom sounds in the stock Mail client without jailbreaking, now the Mac can't either.)

Comment: This does not ring true.  I'm getting custom sounds on my iPhone 11 (v. 16.2), which has never been jailbroken and in Ventura, on a new user account (for some reason - most likely a bug - the 'new message' {and custom} sound does not work in my usual account).